# setInterval array variable is not working in Js

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS.

I need an `array variable which is used to display the values periodically every 1s using setInterval()` inside a function.

The array variable for ex **intV[] (setInterval variable)** should display the values when used in  `console.log(intV[]);` and the values should be stored in `intV[]`.

I tried the below code,

But it didn't work.

```
function date() {
var currentDate = Date.now();
var val = String(currentDate).substr(8, 2);
return val;
}
var intV = [];
function mockData(v) {
   var v = document.getElementById('sample');
    //setInterval function
   intV[v] = setInterval(date, 1000);
   console.log(intV[v]);
}
```

When I did  `console.log(intV[v]);`. **It doesn't display the values every 1s. Instead, it gives a static value Which is not updated every 1s.**

How could i store the values, which is updated every 1s in the `intV[]`.?

Could someone please help?
Many thanks.

Comment: What was unclear about my comments in your [previous question](/q/70031060/4642212) and how is this question different from it? `setInterval` expects a function, or — if you want to use a bad, obsolete, and dangerous API — a string that is a script. You’re passing it part of a date, which makes no sense. The function that you pass to `setInterval` is executed periodically. There is no reason to expect anything outside of a `setInterval` call to be executed periodically. Read the documentation, please: [`setInterval`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/setInterval).

Comment: @SebastianSimon, Yes, I understood that setInterval() expects a function as a parameter. I have edited the code above.  Is the code above is correct? But, I couldn't see the stored values in `intV[]`.

Comment: You didn't read the documentation? Again, `setInterval` returns an identifier to use to break the interval, it doesn't return the value the callback function returns (your callback function doesn't even return anything). If you want to see the calculated value, you've to log it to the console in `date` function.

Comment: Also please be aware that the variable `v` is undefined, and the function `date` doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Teemu ,If the function date returns the val. Will the setInterval function work?

Comment: The return value of the callback function is ignored. Try to understand, that the callback function (`date`) is called from the macro task queue, it's not called from your code.

Comment: @Teemu, So, setInterval(date, 1000) won't work in my code?

Comment: @Teemu, could someone please explain about the setInterval and clearInterval ? Many thanks

Comment: @CuteSako What explanation do you need beyond what is already written in the documentation?

Comment: The interval itself will work, and fire every second. Only that everything you want your code to do in the interval, must be written in the callback function. Like said earlier, "_`setInterval` returns an identifier_", that identifier is an integer, and you can pass that integer to `clearInterval` method to stop that particular interval. Reading the docs will help you, MDN contains a lot of good examples.

Answer (score 0):

The `setInterval` method expects a function as a parameter which is run at each specified interval. All of the logic, including `console.log` needs to be inside of the function that you pass to `setInterval`. I believe the sample provided below provides what you are looking for, but you need to understand that the `intV` array will be populated *AS* the intervals occur, NOT before.

```js
var intV = [];

function date() {
  var currentDate = Date.now();
  var val = String(currentDate).substr(8, 2);
  intV.push(val);
  console.log(intV[intV.length - 1])
}
//setInterval function
setInterval(date, 1000);
```

Comment: @Walker, In this code will clearInterval(intV[]) works?